# Display image from database asp.net vb

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, vb.net, web-applications

I have database

```
 Id     int
 img    varbinary(MAX) --> image
 descr  nvarchar(50)
```

and now I want to display image and description. I use the following code

```
<div>
    <asp:GridView 
        ID="GridView1" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="Id" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceH"
        CssClass="myGridView"
        RowStyle-CssClass="rows"
        ShowHeader="false">

        <Columns>
             <asp:ImageField
                DataImageUrlField = "Id" 
                DataImageUrlFormatString = "Hardware.aspx?Id={0}"
                ControlStyle-Width = "100" 
                ControlStyle-Height = "100"></asp:ImageField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="descr"></asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource 
        runat="server" 
        ID="SqlDataSourceH" 
        ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [img], [descr] FROM [Hardware]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

**but image is not displayed**

[image]

What should I do to display the picture?

Comment: What's the code that responds to the call  that makes `Hardware.aspx?Id={0}`?

Answer (score -1):

Check /Images/theimage.jpg really exists then you need to go into the database and put the full path in the column img.

Also if it is in the folder /Images/ then you need "../Images/theimage.jpg" to go back to the root folder. Check the value of the url copy it to clipboard and dump it in the address bar and see if it comes up, so http://localhost/(dump url here) if it doesn't come up then you need to check the path and update the url value in database.

Comment: I don't think the file path will do any good since it is stored as `varbinary` and uses a handler to load the image.